# HTML5 Validation in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, validation, blazor

I am trying to get the built in HTML5 validation working in my Blazor application but it just gets ignored.

This is my Razor code

```
<form class="row">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com" @bind="@details.Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Phone</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com" @bind="@details.Phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SubmitForm">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>

</div>
@code {
    private ContactDetails details = new ContactDetails();

    public async void SubmitForm()
    {
        var result = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("Contact", details);
    }

}
```

I know I can use Blazors validation, but I want to just use the built in HTML5 validation for this as it is a very basic form. How do I stop the SubmitForm code from being run if the HTML5 validation is triggered?

If I remove the code from the SubmitForm() method obviously nothing then happens when it enters that method and it goes back to the webpage and the html5 validation messages are displayed, however clearly the method is still being fired. Is there a way to stop the code running if there are html5 validation errors?

Comment: I dropped your code into a new Blazor project and the HTML5 validations worked for me both in Chrome and FireFox. `SubmitForm()` would not fire unless I entered valid data.

Comment: Thanks. It is odd that it is not happening for me. I will play around with it to see what is happening.

Comment: So, if I remove the code in the SubmitForm method then it still fires the method but after that the form does display the html validation messages... But it is firing the method no matter what.

Comment: I have even created a new component and replicated the code above in it and it also fires the method.

Comment: As far as Blazor is concerned the button click is just that.  It doesn't recognise the html form, so you have no way to detect html 5 validation.  So the answer is Blazor all the way not some halfway house - use basic Blazor validation and EditForm.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have worked out how to do this.

Simply add and onsubmit event to the Form tag and then remove the onclick from the button.

```
<form class="row" @onsubmit="SubmitForm">
```

This then works as expected.

Now there are clearly lots of benefits to using the built in Blazor forms components but sometimes just working with standard html forms is needed and thankfully there is a solution to do that.

Comment: Bizarre that it worked for me. What build of visual studio are you running? I'm on 16.9.4 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 5.0.5

Comment: Same here. However, looking into it, it looks like it was working as expected and that is was never going to identify the html5 validation.  I have no idea why it was seeming to work for you though...

Answer (score 0):

Use **Regex** by adding this using @using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

**Valid** email : komaei@live.com

**Invalid** emails : komaei , komaei@ , komaei@live.c

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="@nameof(createModel.Email)" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">Email : </label>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-10">
        <InputText type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required
                   id="@nameof(createModel.Email)" @bind-Value="createModel.Email">
        </InputText>
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    private Customer createModel = new();

    private async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        var emailPattern = @"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-‌​]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(emailPattern);
        if (regex.IsMatch(createModel.Email) == false)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Email is not valid!");
            return;
        }

        var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("Customers/Create", createModel);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // 200
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("Customers");
        else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
}
```